# decorators legacy isn't enabled - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

The code is as follows

```
import postActions from './redux/actions/postActions';

@connect(state => ({
  ...state.posts,
}),{
  ...postActions,
})
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "basic-redux-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.19.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5"
  }
}
```

Also, i have created a .babelrc file in the root path.

```
Project Folder
    - node_modules/
    - src/
    - .babelrc
```

and also added the following in the babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-decorators-legacy"],
    // ...
  ]
}
```

I am getting the  following error

> Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't
>   currently enabled

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5708 ?

Comment: @G_S totally unrelated.